# How can I make my PHP application URL's portable across machines and networks?

Tags: php

I have a PHP web application that uses a front controller pattern, with "pretty URLS", e.g.`http://example.com/home/index/params`

The app uses clean URI's - with Apache rewriting behind the scenes,e.g. the above request would be redirected internally to

```
http://example.com/index.php?url=home/index/params
```

However in this case the browser thinks that content is coming from a document called `params` in a directory called `index` and therefore any other requests, e.g. `style.css` would be made to

```
`http://example.com/home/index/style.css`
```

Which of course is wrong, so I am using a variable in PHP to hardcode path requests

```
// constants.php
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/03_my_website_projects/v4/public/')

// views.php
<link href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

produces

```
<link href="http://localhost/03_my_website_projects/v4/public/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The problem is, when I try to visit the website on a mobile device over my local network, I cant view because all the links are hardcoded to an URL addresses that only work from the machine the project is being developed on, 
e.g. my mobile device would want to see a paths like

```
<link href="http://192.168.1.6/03_my_website_projects/v4/public/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How can I make URL's that are portable across machines and networks?

Comment: You might find [`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) useful.

Comment: `va_dump` shows  `'SERVER_NAME' => string 'localhost' (length=9)` wont that still have the same problem? I was thinking either make everything relative or using a bash script to capture the IP address of the local dev machine and substitute the output into the `define ('BASE_URL', $(IPADDRESS) . "......")` or something?

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` will provide the IP address you are expecting if the application is running in such a context. Tip: it will give you whatever is set in `ServerName` in Apache (if you're running Apache) and likewise whatever value you provide to `php -S` if you're using PHP's inbuilt development server.

Comment: do you mean `'SERVER_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1'` or `'REMOTE_ADDR'`  but  yes I think I see what you mean,

Comment: I recommend trying it out in each of your environments to see whether it does what you expect :-)

Comment: thanks, I think I see what you mean.  Will give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

I know Laravel framework has got a really good solution for this (I wish I knew what it was) however this hacky solution is the only thing I could think of that would survive DHCP IP address reassignments.

```
// file: define_constants.php

$ip_address = shell_exec("ip addr show wlan0 | grep 'inet\s' | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'");
define('BASE_URL', 'http://' . $ip_address . '/03_my_website_projects/v4/public/');
```

now all links will use this new addressing, e.g.

```
 <link href="http://192.168.1.6/03_my_website_projects/v4/public/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```